# Discord.py task is not running

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to add a background task to my cog in Discord.py, but the task isn't running.

The cog:

```
class ComicPoster(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot: Bot = bot
        migrate()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5)
    async def comic_update(self):
        print('asdf')
        log.info('Updating all comics')
```

The rest of the cog works (event listeners, commands, etc), but the task never runs for some reason.  How can I get it to run?

Comment: Did you added the, self.comic_update.start() after self.bot definitation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the task. You can do this in the constructor (`__init__`).

Here is what it should look like:

```py
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot: Bot = bot
    migrate()
    # the new line of code
    self.comic_update.start()
```

The `self.comic_update.start()` starts that task and it will loop every five seconds now.